# How to update api details every 10 minute in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-channels

Note: am using django rest framework.

I have a location  model and an apiview for it, I can create, put,  and delete data from the views,  now I want to update this data every 10 minutes from the front-end,  what is the best approach for this. I have come across django channels  but I dont know how to integrate both channels and django rest framework together, since am only updating information.

Comment: *"I want to update this data every 10 minutes from the front-end"* - Wouldn't calling the corresponding API help you?

Comment: Yes,  but won't this cause a work load on the server?  Since different users data will be updated every 10 minutes.